How to define sensor timestamping precision requirements
Consistently timestamped sensor measurements are important for Kalman filtering and for reconstructing events retrospectively. Unfortunately, sometimes people who aren't navigators design these systems, and there is limited or no synchronization between the oscillators for the different onboard sensors. Suppose you need to explain to these people the upper bound on error in timestamping of measurements between two or more sensors.
As background, I know of this happening at at least four different new space companies. Traditional aerospace organizations usually seem to understand the need to discipline to a single master oscillator (except maybe Boeing), but I've heard of a number of groups working on small launch vehicles that don't have any way of time-correlating, say, the accelerometer integration period with the GPS measurements.
One way to look at the requirement is "What is the sensor error resulting from timestamping error $\delta t$ on a measurement taken at wall time $t$?" where $\delta t = \tilde{t}_A(t) - t$ is the instantaneous difference between the internal clock on sensor A and a hypothetical IMU reference oscillator. So if I have a velocimeter taking a measurement $\tilde{v}$, it will also have an error $\delta v = a \delta t$ relative to the IMU measurement at time $t$.
I know that timing errors in acceleration and velocity measurements in Kalman filtering can translate into large position state errors. Where I'm less clear about it is in attitude filtering. While the theory of star tracker functionality is pretty straightforward, there are large differences in implementation that seem to make the attitude measurement error due to timing error a bit less clear. Moreover, the attitude error is directly related to body rate error, which differs by an exponent from the relationship between position error and acceleration error, so it seems like attitude-only systems should be less sensitive to timing error.
Is it possible to write requirements around timing from first principles? Alternatively, are there loose guidelines for timing requirements in different types of systems? Finally, are there other standards aside from PPS for disciplining onboard oscillators?

@uhoh I wasn't a downvoter, but I wasn't an upvoter, either. I'll flip this around at you: Why so many upvotes? Lack of GPS is not a problem. Multiple countries have sent spacecraft well beyond GPS range, so GPS is not the solution.  Even within GPS range, GPS can be jammed, and regularly is jammed over some countries (see gpsjam.org). GPS is not the solution. A 100% reliable and sufficiently stable timing signal is what is needed.

@uhoh That said, at least one of those downvoters should have provided a comment regarding how this question could be improved.

Instead of disciplining several onboard oscillators, you should derive all needed clocks from one single master oscillator. Between all those derived clocks there will be no drift at all.

@DavidHammen when we ask Stack Exchange questions, we often include our current understanding of the situation as a way of helping answer authors to best write an answer that's not only for the world and the future, but for the OP as well. We may not always get everything right, and when we don't, we're subsequently informed and we learn something, from both comments and answer posts. Silent, drive-by downvotes to "teach the OP a lesson" about their understanding are like the teacher whacking the student's knuckles with a ruler, i.e. useless.

@DavidHammen Until one has asked at least a few dozen questions about topics one is unfamiliar with, it's hard to appreciate what Stack Exchange question asking is actually like.

I'm honestly a little bit bewildered by the downvotes also. I've done academic research on state estimation and sensors, worked on a half dozen different missions, and I know what I'm doing. It's possible, even likely, that I could have asked this question better, but the downvotes don't help me to improve its articulation in any meaningful way.

For HETE-2 the processors were synchronized to the microsecond for science, but the ACS didn't even look at the time. The processor computing the control law simply assumed that the data coming in was timely and that the control processor would respond in a timely manner. This led to interprocessor message latency requirements, estimated from back of the envelope control theory and verified in simulation.

But there's some assumption therein that the measurement time error was on the order of microseconds rather than milliseconds, right? There would certainly be a consequence to having such a huge timestamping error, and I'm still wondering how to quantify that consequence.

What about a redundancy swap of any key hardware? In a satellite system (my area of familiarity) an incoming cold processor would be started off with the last good memory of the outgoing processor's working parameters. There would usually be a bit of a satellite attitude wobble but it would recover soon enough. I can't tell whether the question is specifically about launch and whether such topics would be a bit more critical on a launch vehicle than a satellite. Anyway, is this issue relevant to the original question, e.g. is a redundancy swap a relevant source of timestamp imprecision?

Does IRIG count as something other than 1 PPS, or is it part of 1 PPS, because it tells you which second goes with each pulse?  As for the rest, yes, of course it's possible, but the time I participated, it involved dozens of people for a year.  Future system iterations were told they were not allowed to repeat that analysis, but instead ordered to carry over the standards from a decade or two before, because getting the right answer to put in the updated requirements would be too expensive.

I wrote an attitude-only simulation and Kalman filter (with gyro integration, star tracker updates, estimating attitude error and gyro bias) to look at this question. I also (incompletely) tuned it.
This is a dumb way to do this because one can also just derive these numbers from first principles, but sometimes you need to actually put the system together and show it to the customer to truly convince them.
Error between the clocks on the gyroscope and the star tracker tended to add what looked like white noise to the filter. This effect was body rate dependent, as higher body rates produced more disagreement between the gyros and the star trackers when timing error was added.
It's definitely not as serious as in an accelerometer-based pos/vel EKF, but timing does play a role. For a spacecraft rotating at 3 d/s, 100 microseconds of error between star tracker and gyroscope clocks doesn't seem to contribute any additional attitude error, but 500 microseconds does.
On the other hand, for a spacecraft rotating at 0.1 d/s, 10 milliseconds of error produces no meaningful extra attitude error.
Here are some rules of thumb:

1-3 d/s: within 100 microseconds
0.5 d/s: within 1 millisecond
0.2 d/s: within 5 milliseconds
<= 0.1 d/s: within 10 milliseconds is probably fine

I leave the first-principles relationship as an exercise for the reader.

While a lot of computers do have jittery clocks, a simple stable one pulse per second (1PPS) device connected to the computer with a jittery clock helps calm those jitters. Your laptop or desktop computer is very jittery. Running them unassisted by a stable 1PPS signal can wreck havoc with the realtime operating system. Flight software running on a device with a stable 1PPS signal calms those jitters.
(Aside: Been there, done that. I helped write flight software that we implemented on both a flight computer (but not flight certified) and on an expensive desktop. The flight computer, which did have a reasonably stable 1PPS device, had no problems. The desktop implementation kept dropping frames.)
Those simple 1PPS device do not necessarily need GPS input. A decent crystal oscillator is more than good enough to provide the stable 1PPS signal needed by a hard realtime operating system. While the 1PPS signal may drift from that provided by an atomic clock (or GPS), the drift is stable. It's jitter that is the problem, and a decent crystal oscillator counters that jitter.

Hi @david-hammen, it's great to hear from you, long time no talk. I'm not asking about stability or jitter. I'm asking about consistency of timestamping on different sensors that might be disciplined by different oscillators.

@Translunar This is a solved problem, and has been solved without relying on GPS, which is unreliable. Whenever the ISS passes over certain countries the vehicle experiences GPS outages. GPS is unreliable, even in LEO. And it is certainly unreliable for vehicles that travel beyond GPS range.

@David-Hammen I'm also not asking about GPS. I used GPS as one example of such a reference. I'm aware those references can take other forms, including the oscillator in a flight computer. I'm asking about situations where someone uses oscillators that don't communicate with each other. Imagine you have two flight computers, and one has an IMU and another has a velocimeter, and each is timestamped independently. (And yes, I realize this is a bad design, and yet — sometimes we have to work with what we are given, and ask dumb questions about bad designs.)

I've removed GPS from my question entirely, because it seems to be producing confusion.

@Translunar "Never go to sea with two chronometers; take one or three." That also applies to going into space. This is the essence of the Byzantine Generals Problem. Google that term, and read Leslie Lamport's paper. If you are faced with a very bad design, speak out! This is admittedly easy to say by someone who is retired. That said, I did speak out about bad designs when is was working. Sometimes, it worked. Other times, it did not. And one time, I was let go (but I did find a new job the next week).

I'm glad you found something quickly. I remember that and I was sad to see you go. As I'm sure you realize, design changes require cost/benefit analyses. So I'm left with the question I posed, which is "How do I quantify the effects of poor timestamping of sensor measurements?"

You're overthinking this. Ordinary crystal oscillators are more than adequate for attitude control.
Edit:
It's useful to think in terms of the timing of the attitude perturbations you're attempting to suppress. For an orbiting spacecraft, most of the external perturbations are cyclic with periods of one half an orbit or a full orbit. So they are pretty slow, thousands of seconds even in LEO.
Even in LEO, the perturbing torques are small. For example, HETE-2 would only drift off target by a few tens of degrees over ~2000 second eclipse if the star trackers weren't operational. In higher orbits, the perturbations are smaller.
Very crudely, if you're trying to reduce the effect of a cyclic perturbation by a factor of X, the allowable "fuzzyness" in your timing is the time scale of the perturbation divided by X. So, in LEO, for a reduction of a factor of 1000, you might guess you need timing precision of a few seconds. Again, that's the HETE-2 case.

Yes, but they have to be disciplined to a common reference time. If the two sensors are on different flight computers and there's no alignment between the timing of the two flight computers, for example, then there's no way to correlate the measurements in time.

@Translunar It's not that difficult to keep flight computer timing consistent, one way or another. No need for an external absolute reference like GPS.

I am aware it's not that difficult. And yet sometimes to convince people to change designs, I have to justify things that folks working in traditional aerospace organizations take for granted. Saying "it's not that difficult" doesn't help bridge that gap in any meaningful way.

@Translunar So why the obsession with GPS? That's actually not a great way to sync a multiprocessor system, need a GPS receiver for each processor.

No obsession with GPS; as I said, I'm asking about a GPSless system. I only mentioned it because PPS is a common standard used for disciplining sensors and oscillators, and GPS provides that.

@Translunar You don't need tight discipline for ACS (but maybe you need it for science). Anyway, it's easy enough to make a PPS with a good oscillator and a divider chain.

Which brings us back to the original question: when you say "you don't need tight discipline," how do you define tight? What discipline is needed?
